Get query params of powerpoint-web from microsoft add-ins
I am redirecting user to the microsoft web page from my react app and passing extra query params with it (myValue) something like

oneDrive.live.com/extraCode/Doc.aspx?resid=A&cid=B&myValue=123

Now I have a microsoft addin created for powerpoint web(running in localhost as of now). Can I somehow get that value in my addin ?
Since my addin is running in a different domain -

window.location.href

will not give me powerpoint url but the domain where addin is deployed.If not possible is there any other way I can get these values in my addin when I redirect from my application to powerpoint?

Please explain what you mean by "the microsoft web page", "powerpoint web", and "powerpoint url", and "redirect ... to powerpoint".

Hi thanks for asking. By microsoft web page I meant opening a powerpoint that is stored in oneDrive on web.
So it's like a oneDrive url something like that-
https://onedrive.live.com/personal/58273aa884e44ccb/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?resid=58273AA884E44CCB!s4f5ac62fc5234117ad06af485f8d527b&cid=58273aa884e44ccb&migratedtospo=true&app=PowerPoint
I am redirecting to that url .

I don't think there's a way of doing that, but you might want to investigate the document properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.documentproperties

There's not much examples shown for me to use document properties method. If you know how to use it to get the metadata of the presentation like author etc. , please tell me how to use it? On which method specifically . It is a preview version right? is it even available?
